# Bootstrap 100% height (content so footer sticks to bottom)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

How would one go about forcing the footer to 'hug' the bottom of the page if the content does not fill the page?

I've tried all sorts of combinations of 100% height/max-height div's but cannot get the footer to play ball...

Site: [moorparksdevon.uk](http://moorparksdevon.uk)

[image: Img from phone]

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets along with your question.

Comment: How does one post relevant code snippets for an entire website? I'm not entirely sure what part should have the CSS hence a URL provided.

Comment: You don't post code for an entire website. You create an MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you are using twitter-bootstrap this can be one solution. Add the following to your footer div--- `<div class="footer navbar-fixed-bottom">`

Also add this css to your page---

```
html,body{
height: 100%
}
```

Above points can solve your problem keeping in mind you can't provide your whole code.